# How to merge results of two queries in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to take the data of the child called news to a list. Can I get the department key only when all or Management?

Here is my code:

```
query = MainNewsDb.orderByChild("department").equalTo("Management").limitToLast((int)limit);
query.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener1);

query1 = NewsListDb1.orderByChild("department").equalTo("all").limitToLast((int)limit);
query1.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener1);
```

This Is My RTDB:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "Can I get the department key only when all or Management?"?

Comment: @AlexMamo I want to show the news issued for all the departments along with the news of the department under consideration among the news released to several departments.(My database image in the question)

Comment: So you want to get the result of a combined query? Is that what you need?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes sir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the combined result of two separate Firebase Realtime Database queries, I recommend you to use [Tasks.whenAllSuccess()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks#whenAllSuccess(com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task%3C?%3E...)) method. You can achieve this, using the following lines of code:

```
query = MainNewsDb.orderByChild("department").equalTo("Management").limitToLast((int)limit);
query1 = NewsListDb1.orderByChild("department").equalTo("all").limitToLast((int)limit);

Task firstTask = query.get();
Task secondTask = query1.get();

Task combinedTask = Tasks.whenAllSuccess(firstTask, secondTask).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<Object>>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(List<Object> list) {
         //Do what you need to do with your list
    }
});
```

As you can see, when overriding the "onSuccess()" method the result is a list of objects. As soon as you have it, simply map each object from the list into an object of the desired type.